# How to select records only in table b

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have two tables. Table A and Table B. they both have two columns (Name and Salary). Both tables have duplicate name records but the salary is different. How can i write a query to select the name and salary of Table A where the name of table A is in table B's Name column.

MYSQL or MSSQL

```
Table A 
Name        Salary
john smith  100
john smith  100
sally smith 100
Dan smith   100


Table B 
Name        Salary
john smith  100
john smith  100
sally smith 100

result  
Name    Salary
john smith  100
john smith  100
sally smith 100
```

Comment: There EXISTS more than one way to JOIN these tables to understand the INNER details of the data.

Comment: can i use a join though if the data column i'm using in my on statement has duplicates in both tables?

Comment: Your description and your title are totally different.  This is one reason why sample data and desired results are so important.

Comment: Use `JOIN TableB ON TableA.Name = TableB.Name`

Comment: i added some demo data

Comment: @SteveShort Use Sean's suggestion of EXISTS. You don't need a join.

Comment: @Error_2646 i think you are right. but do you know, any join that can do what is needed? I believe join actually can't do it because of the duplicates, do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, Salary
  FROM Table_A
 WHERE Name IN (SELECT DISTINCT Name
                  FROM Table_B)      ;
```